# pg_send_query_params Returns TRUE But Fails

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I have a PHP script which inserts a row into a Postgres DB. It works fine on my test server (Postgres 9.1) but fails on my new shared host (Postgres 8.4).

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP(0), $3, $4, ST_Point($4, $3))";
$result = pg_send_query_params($dbconn, $query, array($is_happy, $rate, $lat, $lon));
```

The `$result` is always TRUE but no row is inserted.

I also tried:

```
$result = pg_get_result($dbconn);
```

But experienced the same behaviour.

Following @CraigRinger's transaction suggestion below I also tried both:

```
$query = "BEGIN;INSERT INTO " . $table . " VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP(0), $3, $4, ST_Point($4, $3));COMMIT;";
$result = pg_send_query_params($dbconn, $query, array($is_happy, $rate, $lat, $lon));
```

and

```
pg_send_query($dbconn, "BEGIN;");
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP(0), $3, $4, ST_Point($4, $3));";
$result = pg_send_query_params($dbconn, $query, array($is_happy, $rate, $lat, $lon));
pg_send_query($dbconn, "COMMIT;");
```

And still got the same behaviour.

If I run the INSERT query in phpPgAdmin a row is inserted. I am also able to get the results from this query in a PHP script:

```
"SELECT relid FROM pg_stat_user_tables"
```

What does this mean when the INSERT query result is true but no row is inserted? What could be the problem and how might I approach resolving this?

**Edit**

I can `INSERT` rows using phpPgAdmin and then `SELECT` these rows from a PHP script.

Here is a full PHP script that fails (it is stripped of POST gathering and validation that exists in my full script). The `rest.php` script simply holds connection vars and a response function. This `rest.php` script works with my `SELECT` script:

```
<?php
require "KLogger.php";
require "rest.php";

ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);

$log   = KLogger::instance(dirname(__FILE__), KLogger::DEBUG);
$log_id = "AM".time();
$log->logInfo($log_id . " *** " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$lat = '51.510199';
$lon = '-0.129654';
$rate = '10';
$is_happy = 't';

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=" . $host . " dbname=" . $db . " user=" . $user . " password=" . $pw);
if(!$dbconn)
{
    $log->logInfo($log_id . " No connection: " . pg_last_error());
    sendResponse(500, "Internal Server Error");
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP(0), $3, $4, ST_Point($4, $3));";
    $result = pg_send_query_params($dbconn, $query, array($is_happy, $rate, $lat, $lon));
    if(!$result)
    {
        $log->logInfo($log_id . " No Result: " . pg_last_error());
        sendResponse(500, "Internal Server Error");
    }
    else
    {
        $log->logInfo($log_id . " sendResponse(200)");
        sendResponse(200, "OK");
    }
}
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: How are you determining that "no row is inserted"?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I am browsing the table with phpPgAdmin.

Comment: So what makes you sure that phpPgAdmin isn't at fault? Tried a `SELECT` from `psql`? Are you absolutely certain that you are connecting to the same database?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I can INSERT and SELECT a row using phpPgAdmin. So this tool seems to be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this kind of issue is an open, uncomitted transaction.

If you `BEGIN` (or do so implicitly by turning autocommit off in your database driver) then do some work, only the transaction that did the work can see the changes until it `COMMIT`s.

If that is the case then an immediate follow-up query from within the same script using the same connection will see the changed row, but nothing else will.

You can also check for this by enabling:

```
log_statement = 'all'
log_line_prefix = 'db=%d pid=%p vtxid=%v txid=%x'
```

and finding mismatched transactions by looking for virtual transaction IDs (`vtxid`) with a `BEGIN` and no matching `COMMIT`.

If you can't modify `postgresql.conf` because it's shared hosting you should be able to `ALTER USER myuser SET log_statement = 'all';` or `ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET log_statement = 'all';`. You can't set `log_line_prefix` outside `postgresql.conf` but your host might have a reasonable setting already.

---

Another possibility - and one that might be explained by the version difference - is that you're triggering an error later in the transaction by using a feature only available in 9.1, and you aren't detecting that error. Your earlier `INSERT` succeeds, but the whole transaction then gets rolled back when the later statement fails. Again, examine the server logs to see.

---

Another common cause is that you're connecting to a different database with the script than the one you connect to when you test to see if it's inserted. Try `SELECT`ing the row you expect to have been inserted from the script after you insert it. It's also worth creating a dummy table via your admin tool (phpPgAdmin in your case, it seems) and then testing to see whether the script can see the dummy table.

Comment: I do not have access to the `postgresql.conf`. If I run your ALTER statements in phpPgAdmin I get 'Permission Denied'. I have tried wrapping the INSERT statement in a transaction but no change (see my amended question for details). If I run the SQL INSERT statement in phpPgAdmin it works. The INSERT is the only SQL in my PHP script. Please do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Polly As I said, try `SELECT`ing after the `INSERT` to see if that run of that script sees the new data immediately after it's inserted. As for `permission denied` I'm guessing you weren't running them as the database owner (for the database-level one) or a superuser or `createuser` user (for the user level one)

Comment: @Polly Also: **could you be connecting to a different database with your script vs your test?** See updated answer.

Comment: Both phpPgAdmin and my script are using the same host and dbname. If I `SELECT`immediately after the `INSERT` no rows are returned. If I use incorrect password I do not get a connection. However, if I use an invalid table name I get no error! The table I am trying to insert into was created in phpPgAdmin.

Comment: Also, If I `INSERT` a row with phpPgAdmin I can `SELECT` it in my script.

Comment: I have added the full script to my question just in case it helps.

Comment: @Polly Sounds like the `INSERT` is failing and you aren't getting an error from PHP. Examine the PostgreSQL error logs. If that doesn't tell you anything then `SET log_statement = 'all';` in your script before the `INSERT` and look at the logs, make sure the `INSERT` actually shows up in the logs.

Comment: I switched to PDO and an exception was returned. My problem was data types. I had numeric cols but my values were seen as doubles. 9.1 seems more tolerant than 8.4 in this issue. Thanks for your help.